# Find the distribution of a random variablee

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am reading again an introduction to basic probability and I came a cross this question.

Knowing that $X \sim U[3,9]$, find the distribution for the random variable $Y=\text{min} \{X,c \}$ such that $c \in [3,9]$, then calculate the mean *(if exist)*.

I searched the site here and I found the same [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61171/minimum-of-a-constant-and-a-random-variable). Although it is answered and I already studied this course previously, I don't get the solution! Is there anyone can clarify more the answer?

Comment: What did you not understand about the answer to the question as asked before?

Comment: @Math1000 a way to represent the density as $\text{d}P_{Y_t}(x)=\mathbf{1}_{[0,t]}(x)\text{d}x+(1-t)\delta_t(\text{d}x).$ BUT this is not the density! and what does this mean? and what are the consequences of what he found? I understood the distribution is a mixture of continues and discrete but I didn't understand what to do after

Answer (score 0):

$Y$ has distribution as follows:
$$Y = \left\{\begin{array}{l} Y_1 = U[3,c] & P(Y_1) = \frac{c-3}{6} \\  Y_2 = U[c,c] & P(Y_2) = \frac{9-c}{6} \\ \end{array}\right\}$$

For $Y_1$, since $F_{Y_1}=F_{X|X \leqslant c}(X)$ is distributed uniformly as $U[3,c]$. In fact, $Y_1$ inherit Uniformity from $X$.

For $Y_2$, obviously $F_{Y_2}=c$. I write it as $U[c,c]$, just for symmetry and beauty.

Comment: Thanks..could you add a clarification for what you did? Why you assumed that Y follows a uniform distribution?

Comment: I add some clarification. Hope Help.